# RegEx in PHP file

Tags: module, magento-1, php-5.4, validation, regex

I would like to **place a RegEx Code in PHP code to validate a password**. Example below of current code:

```
if (strlen($password) && !Zend_Validate::is($password, 'StringLength', array(6))) {
    $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('The minimum password length is %s', 6);
}
```

I would like to replace the `array(6)` with this regular expression with `preg_match`:

```
preg_match("/(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&])[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%^&]{10,16}/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (strlen($password) && !Zend_Validate::is($password, 'Regex', array('/(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&])[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%^&]{10,16}/')) {
    $errors[] = Mage::helper('customer')->__('your error message here');
}
```

Comment: 3rd parameter must be an array (see my answer) ;)

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism, yep but it must have the key `pattern` in it. See my update answer :) https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/lib/Zend/Validate/Regex.php#L68. And it works with a simple string also

Comment: Sure about the key `pattern` ? https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.9.2.4/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Block.php#L56

Comment: Oh ok yeah here we go again posting the same answers ;)

Answer (score 3):

I reckon you should **use `Zend_Validate_Regex` in that case.**

You could do:

```
$validate = new Zend_Validate_Regex("/(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&])[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%^&]{10,16}/");

if (strlen($password) && !$validate->isValid($password)) {
}
```

### Alternative

You can also do:

```
if (strlen($password) && !Zend_Validate::is($password, 'Regex', array("/(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$%^&])[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%^&]{10,16}/"))) {
}
```

Comment: Thank you @RaphaelatDigitalPianism I will test the code.